# How do I select a folder in the SaveAs Dialog using pywinauto?

Tags: python, automation, pywinauto

I need to specify a destination folder for a file i download with pywinauto.
It's not possible to write the entire filepath in the filename editbox. I tried this.
Here's a screenshot of the dialog:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried press Enter after you had posted a full path?

It works for me. I placed full path, pressed Enter and then pressed Save.